# Php closure function as parameter to preg_replace_callback results in Internal Server Error 500

Tags: php, callback, preg-replace, closures, internal-server-error

I have a `preg_replace_callback` which takes a closure (anonymous) function as 2nd parameter and it works perfectly fine on local, but when I deploy it to live environment it results in error => Internal server error 500. When i remove the Closure it works.

```
$regExPattern = '/\<%(?<content>.*?)%\>/';
$template = preg_replace_callback($regExPattern, function ($matches)  use ($dataItem) {
    if(isset($dataItem[trim($matches['content'])])) {
        return $dataItem[trim($matches['content'])];
    }
    else {
        return '';
    }
}, $template);
```

Any suggestions how can i work arround this problem. I need to use $dataItem inside my callback function and pass it to `preg_replace_callback`.
My development environment is code igniter.

Comment: Your production server is not outputting the error, which is good design. Can you check the error log and let us know what the actual error is?

Comment: any chance you don't have php 5.3 on your development environment ?

Comment: Like @boobiq I'm guessing there's a high likelihood your server isn't using PHP 5.3

Comment: yes you are right, PHP Version 5.2.17. Can you help me passing a function to the preg_replace_callback and having $dataItem inside of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous functions only work in PHP 5.3 and up. You could use `create_function()` instead:

```
$regExPattern = '/\<%(?<content>.*?)%\>/';
$template = preg_replace_callback($regExPattern, create_function(
      '$matches'
    , 'if(isset($dataItem[trim($matches[\'content\'])])) {
          return $dataItem[trim($matches[\'content\'])];
      }
      else {
          return "";
      }'
    )
);
```

Untested, of course.

Comment: Thank you. But i don't rly like writing code as a string. So i passed the function like array($this, 'functionName') and declared it in the body of the class: private function functionName. Thank you :)

Comment: Yeah, that would be the other alternative. I'm not sure if it works with private functions, but I presume you tested.